# How is this definition of main in C acceptable to the compiler

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Why does the following piece of code compile error free?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(aaa) { // <-- This argument is what I consider rubbish
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

I am just trying to define main() with random rubbish and see what error a compiler(`gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)`) throws up.

Comment: That should answer your question.

Comment: This is because GCC before version 5.0 defaults to the gnu90 standard, which is C90 + non-standard extensions. C90 allowed "implicit int". Details about the allowed forms of main can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518).

Comment: @2501 Actually I'm not sure if that duplicate answers the question, because it is not clear why `int main (int)` would be an acceptable form of main. One would have to refer to some GCC document describing the allowed implementation-defined forms of main.

Comment: main can be implementation defined as anything according to the Standard anyway.

Comment: @2501 Only if the compiler documents it. If the compiler allows a special kind of main, and it is not documented, then the compiler is not conforming.